# Resolve #error when summing text box values that result from an MS Access 2010 IIF statement

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

The image attached shows a bunch of timestamps when various actions are taken in a factory.

The `FINISHED` column value is populated by an `IIF` statement posted below.

```
=IIf(IsNull([DateStampCleaning]),0,IIf(([DateStampCleaning]>=[Forms]![frmIndividualBuildActivity]![txtFrom]) And ([DateStampCleaning]>=[Forms]![frmIndividualBuildActivity]![txtTo]+1),0,[quantity]))
```

The column value is set to `0` either if there is no value in 'Cleaning Started' or if the date falls outside of the dates you see at the top of the form.

The `IIF` statement seems to work fine, however when I try to SUM the column, I simply get `#Error`

For clarity - Items in the BLUE box show 0 because the date falls outside of our range. Items in the RED box show a figure from the quantity column.

The text box that holds the `IIF` statement is called `txtFinished` and in my total box at the bottom (circled) I simply have `=Sum([txtFinished])` in the control source.

Can anyone advise me please where I am going wrong?

Incidentally, the `QTY` total on the left works perfectly until I try and total the `FINISHED` column which seems strange.

[Enlarge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cfk6M.png)

[image: IMAGE LINK]

Will be very grateful for some pointers.

Comment: Make sure all the values that you attempt to do math on are non-null and numerical.

Comment: Many thanks. The box this question relates to - and the box I am performing a sum on - is '[txtFinished]' which has a Format of Fixed to 0 Decimal Places. I tried changing it to General Number but this did not help. The other box 'quantity' which underlies part of the sum is also a 'General Number'. 

I take your point about Null however as far as I can see my IIF statement repalces Null's with a Zero, assuming I have done it correctly?

Comment: `Incidentally, the QTY total on the left works perfectly until I try and total the FINISHED column which seems strange.` This is standard Access behavior, if one aggregation fails, they all fail.

Comment: Thanks all for your input so far, though none of these answers resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Change `[quantity]` to `Nz([quantity])`

This will return `0` when `[quantity]` is null, ensuring the values summed are always numerical.

When the second argument is omitted, the `Nz` function will return `0` for null numerical arguments, and an empty string (`""`) for null string arguments. However, you can explicitly specify that the function return `0` using `Nz([quantity],0)`

Comment: Many thanks. There are no null values on qty, in fact all 4024 lines in that table have a numerical value (I just checked) :-)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should read:

```
[DateStampCleaning]<=[Forms]![frmIndividualBuildActivity]![txtTo]
```

Comment: Thanks Gustav.... good spot. I also had my truepart and falsepart the wrong way round :0)